# Modificar Rangos de elementos de MarkerClusterer v3 Gmap.js

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Consulta: necesito modificar los rangos de elementos que se agrupan en MarkerClusterer, osea que cuando aparezcan los cluster de color (que al final son imagenes que yo mismo le seteo), cada uno represente una cantidad de elementos determinada por mi, y no la que viene por defecto con la API.

Saludos y espero alguna respuesta!!!!

MarkerClusterer v3:  https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

Answer (score 0):

Si miras en la página que enlazas, hay una lista desplegable que permite cambiar el tamaño del cluster (que parece que es lo que quieres). El valor de esa lista se pasa al parámetro `gridSize` cuando se crea/refresca el mapa:

```
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: zoom,
    gridSize: size, // ---------------- AQUI
    styles: styles[style],
    imagePath: '../images/m'
});
```

Esa propiedad tiene sus *getter* y *setter* para leer y escribir el valor (`getGridSize` y `setGridSize` respectivamente).

Aunque mirando la [documentación](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html), parece que `minimumClusterSize` es realmnete lo que estás buscando. `gridSize` se utiliza para indicar el tamaño de la cuadrícula de un clúster en píxeles, mientras que `minimumClusterSize` es para indicar el número mínimo de marcadores que estarán en un clúster antes de que se oculten y se actualice la cuenta.

Comment: gracias por responder, si tenia claro ese parámetro pero yo necesito 3 setear rangos distintos ( de 0 a 5, de 6 a 15 y mas de 15)) ahi esta mi problema.

Comment: OK. Voy a ver si encuentro algo sobre eso. Si no encuentro nada, borraré esta respuesta.